# sum function returns sum of iterator but how can this code works?

Tags: python

```
print(sum(map(int,input())))
```

I googled definition of sum, and it said sum function add all the number in iterator.
I believe iterator is list, tuple, dictionary, set.
When i input 123, it returns 6.
But 123 is not a iterator...

Comment: [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator. That's what you're passing to `sum`.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you actually want - sum up all integers given? E.g. should the input `123` return `6` ?

Comment: `123` is not an iterator, but `'123'` is a string which is iterable and `map()` can iterate over it.

Comment: I think Pythonkr wants to understand the behaviour.

Comment: thank you so much for helping i didnt know map return iterator and string is iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is great for exploration - when something is mysterious, examine it interactively.

Example:

```
>>> x = input()
123
>>> x
'123'
>>> map(int, x)
<map object at 0x7f692821cc40>
>>> for i in map(int, x): print(i)
...
1
2
3
>>> list(map(int,x))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can help to split it like this:

```
x = input()
print(x)
y = map(int, x)
print(y)
z = sum(y)
print(z)
```

The map takes your string that you enter (like '123') and converts it to an iterator with integers like [1, 2, 3]. That can be summed up in the next step.

This gives:

```
123
<map object at 0x7fb91affdd30>
6
```

Comment: Please update your answer with the actual outputs.

Answer (score 0):

map(int, '123') returns the iterable [1, 2, 3] as you can see by executing this:

```
for x in (map(int, '123')):
    print(x)
```

the sum of this iterable is 6

Answer (score 0):

While you are running the code,

```
print(sum(map(int, input())))
```

It takes the input as string which is a iterable, then it comes to `.map()` function which converts each string type value into integer type as `int` has passed as argument and returns a iterator. Then the `.sum()` function adds all the element in the temporary list and prints the output.

To mark the difference run the below code which will give you a error output saying, `"TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"` as while we will take input, we are converting it into integer (Not Iterator) and then passing to `.map()` function,

```
print(sum(map(int, int(input()))))
```

Comment: This answer contains a number of factual errors.

Comment: So, yes, the `input()` *is* a string. Its not an iterator, but it *is* iterable.

Comment: And `map()` returns an iterator which `sum()` can iterate over.

Comment: Sorry for the type mistakes, I have made those correct.